# Angular form fields in a child component turns red when navigating between the child components used in a stepper component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component called program-stepper that has 2 child component called create-workout and create-program as the code shows below:
the problem that the forms fields in the child components turns red when I navigate between the 2 components and did not touch any field yet, [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bskqjs-h63k76)

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="true">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Create Program</ng-template>
      <app-create-program [program]="program" [editMode]="editMode" [programId]="programId" ></app-create-program>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Create Workout</ng-template>
      <app-create-workout [editMode]="editMode" [programId]="programId" [trainingDays]="trainingDays"></app-create-workout>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
        <button mat-button [disabled]="!areAllFormsValid()" (click)="onDoneClick()" *ngIf="!editMode">Done</button>
      </div>
    </mat-step>
  </ng-container>
```

this is code of create-program component:

```
export class CreateProgramComponent implements OnInit {
  validationMessages: { [key: string]: { [key: string]: string } };
  programForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() athleteId: string;
  @Input() editMode: boolean;
  @Input() programId: string;
  @Input() program: ProgramDisplay;
  
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CreateProgramComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private programService: ProgramService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private utilityService: UtilityService,
    private datePipe: DatePipe
  ) {
    this.validationMessages = {
      title: {
        required: 'Title is required',
      },
      start_date: {
        required: 'Start date is required',
      },
      end_date: {
        required: 'End date is required',
      }
    };
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {    
    this.createForm();
    if(this.editMode){
      this.loadDataForEditMode();
    }
  }

  createForm(){
    this.programForm = this.fb.group({
      title: [null, [Validators.required]],
      start_date: [null, [Validators.required]],
      end_date: [null, [Validators.required]],
    });
  }

  isFieldValid(field: string): boolean | undefined {
    const control = this.programForm.get(field);
    return control?.touched && !control.valid && control.dirty;
  }
```

I want to prevent the fields from turning red when the user did not touch them yet and when navigating from one component to another, note that the form validation works correctly when i don't navigate . how to achieve this behaviour, thank you!

Comment: please share a working stackblitz  with the issue replicated for debugging, the current question does not have all the required details!

Comment: I tried an approach by adding(selectionChange) in the stepper that calls a method to verify if the field is not touched yet it will set the form field errors to null "control.setErrors(null)" but with this approach the field is considered valid( when the user writes something the validation works fine), but i am not sure will make sure to fill all the fields.

Comment: okay I will share on stackblitz in few minutes

Comment: here is a reference [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bskqjs?file=src%2Fexample%2Fstepper-animations-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fstepper-animations-example.ts)

Comment: The stepper expects each step to be completed and automatically performs validation when you move to the next step. Depending on your requirements, you may be able to set the `optional` property on the step to prevent this. In some cases, I have manually (i.e., in the component TS) set the `interacted` property of the step to prevent unwanted validation.

Comment: I want to give flexibility to the user to navigation between the 2 steps, but the submit button in the stepper will be available until all the form fields between the 2 components are valid. using `optional` do not solve the issue btw

Comment: @NarenMurali, any updates on my code and the scenario I am trying to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, I got it working using the input property `errorStateMatcher` of angular material, where you set the condition on which the errors need to be shown, please find below a working example where your requirement seems to work fine!

html adding the matcher

```
...
<form [formGroup]="programForm">
        <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
          <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
          <input
            matInput
            formControlName="title"
            placeholder="Program Title"
            [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
          />
          <!-- <mat-error *ngIf="isFieldValid('title')">
            {{ validationMessages['title']['required'] }}
          </mat-error> -->
        </mat-form-field>
        ...
```

and in the TS it will be

```
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(
    control: FormControl | null,
    form: FormGroupDirective | null
  ): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(
      control &&
      control.invalid &&
      (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted)
    );
  }
}
...
export class CreateProgramComponent implements OnInit {
  matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-evki8d?file=src%2Fcreate-program%2Fcreate-program.component.ts,src%2Fcreate-program%2Fcreate-program.component.html,src%2Fprogram-stepper%2Fprogram-stepper.component.ts)